# Shorthand for undefined property, initialize and assign property in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to see if their is a shorthand way to test for an undefined property, if so initialize it or assign it something.

```
obj: {
   array: [];
}
obj.array.push(something);
```

If `array` wasnt a part of `obj`, how would I test this in the shortest way possible and still push something to it.  Reason is I want to cut down on the size of a http request with properties that are NULL, and my objects have a lot of properties.

Comment: You have syntax error. `array:  []` Also if `obj` is not part of another object then you have to declare it first like `var obj = { array: [] }; `

Comment: Which property do you want to test for being undefined?

Comment: Looks like you confused `:` and `=`. Can you show us your whole code, please? It looks like you're creating those properties in the first place, so you would know that they are not undefined?

Comment: I am using an example with the property, read the whole question as I state if array WASNT a part of obj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an assignment which checks the property and use an array if not exist.

```
(obj.array = obj.array || []).push(value);
```

```js
var obj = {},
    checkNPush = (o, k, v) => (o[k] = o[k] || []).push(v);

(obj.array = obj.array || []).push(42);
(obj.array = obj.array || []).push(43);

checkNPush(obj, 'array', 44);

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes I was thinking of doing this  but was curious if their was something shorter as I would hate to do this all over the place but might have to.

Comment: you could use a function for it.

Comment: There we go, pretty cool.  Probably need to have one for properties which arent arrays too.